# Rails: Issues while using Octopus Gem for database sharding

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, octopus

I am using Octopus gem to handle database sharding in my application. I have a master and a slave. The insert query always hits the master and the read goes to slave.

But I am facing a weird issue like, after inserting a record and when I try to fetch it, record is not found. This is affecting my whole application.
I tried to resolve this issue by the following code.

```
Model.using(:master).where(id: 250)
```

This will force the model to fetch record from master rather than from slave. But if we add this everywhere in the application there is no point of sharding.

Any solution for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to fun world of asynchronous replication.

Generally, when updating data to your master database, the data is replicated asynchronously to the slaves, meaning it will arrive there at any later point in time. Unfortunately, you can't known when that will happen as the only thing typically guaranteed is the order of updates to the slave, not when they will happen.

Often, you'll try to keep the replication delay rather small but you can't ignore it. Generally, when using asynchronous replication, you have to think critically about your data access strategies to avoid presenting unwanted stale data.

Sharding and replication definitely doesn't come for free. Database systems try hard to implement strongly defined levels of atomicity via transactions but due to [CAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem), things get more complicated (or sometimes impossible) when introducing a distributed system.

There isn't a generally correct answer for this issue as it is not directly clear, which data can be stale and which doesn't. Think about your access patterns and chose the appropriate server. Often, the simplest answer is to get rid of sharding and replication completely and to simply use a bigger server.